# addEventListener("popstate") not firing for .document

Tags: javascript, ajax, popstate

Using Ajax and trying to create a popstate event handler on the actual Ajax page using the .document object:

```
document.addEventListener("popstate", myPopState);
```

Unfortunately this does not ever seem to trigger.

My intention being that after the page is reloaded the popstate event trigger will automatically disappear.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("popstate", myPopState);`

Answer (score 1):

inside ajax success response , you could use

```
         var msg="Any thing which u want";
         var customUrl ="www.stackoverflow.com";

 window.history.pushState({"html":msg,"pageTitle":"My Title"},"", customUrl);
       window.onpopstate = function(event) {
             alert('back is clicked');
           // what ever u want
       }
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(window).unload(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).trigger('beforeunload');   

});


$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){

alert('call your ajax here');
    return '';
});
```

Comment: but doesn't the onpopstate event listener then remain permanently so it continues to get called everytime 'back' is clicked?

Comment: @NickC you can bind call on document.

Comment: How would I do that?
window.addEventListener("popstate", myPopState).bind(document) ?

Comment: Any way to do it without JQuery?